# Galois Theory and Polynomials Discriminant

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I am trying to show for some complex numbers `$l_j , 1 ≤ j ≤ 5$

$∆(x_1, x_2, x_3)=l_1σ^2_{3,3} + l_2σ_{3,1}σ_{3,2}σ_{3,3} + l_3σ^3_{3,1}σ_{3,3}+ l_4σ^3_{3,2} + l_5σ^2_{3,1}σ^2_{3,2}$.

Second, by using the polynomial $x^
3 − 1$,  want to show that $l_1 = −27$.

I know the discriminant $∆_{y3+py+q} = −4p^3 − 27q^
2$ and P is a symmetric polynomial if for any permutation $σ$ of the subscripts $1, 2, \ldots, n$ one has $F(X_{σ(1)},\ldots, X_{σ(n)}) = P(X_1,\ldots, X_n)$. But I am not sure how to proceed in the above example.

Comment: Could you illustrate how the function would better compute $l_1$ ?

Comment: if $\sigma_{3,1} = \sigma_{3,2} = 0$ then $\Delta = l_1 \sigma_{3,3}^2$ so you can compute $l_1$ with knowledge of $\Delta$ and $\sigma_{3,3}^2$, both of which can be computed directly with the roots.  My previous comment was mistaken, $\sigma_{3,1} = \sigma_{3,2}$ in the case of $x^3-1$.

Comment: Ahh could you show how the computation works, appreciate it!